# Problems with tikzcd diagrams

Tags: tikz-cd

I *have* thought of asking 3 different questions, but then they are all about the same package, and about fiddling with arrows, so they are all related, so I thought I'd go with one. Here we go. My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,newtxmath,newtxtext,tikz-cd,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning,cd}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
a \ar[r,leftarrow] \ar[d,rightarrow,red] & id \ar[r,rightarrow,red] & b \ar[d,rightarrow] \\
ab \ar[d,rightarrow] & & ba \ar[d,rightarrow,red] \\
aba \ar[loop left,blue,no head] \ar[rrr,bend left=24,blue,xshift=-5.5ex,yshift=-.4ex,no head] \ar[rrr,bend right=22,blue,xshift=-5.5ex,yshift=.4ex,no head] & & bab \ar[loop right,blue,phantom,"\scalebox{.3}{\bfseries)}",xshift=-2.6ex,yshift=-.5ex] & {\color{white}a}
\end{tikzcd}\]
\[\begin{tikzcd}
G \ar[d,thick, start anchor=center, end anchor=center, xshift=-.5em, decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror},"abel"'] \ar[d,no head] \\
N \\
G' \ar[d,dashed,no head] \\
\left\langle\mathcal{C}_1\right\rangle \ar[d,no head] \\
1
\end{tikzcd}\]
\[\begin{tikzcd}
 & & 3 \ar[loop below,red,"b"] \ar[dr,green,"c"] \\
V \ar[loop,blue,"a",out=160,in=110] \ar[loop,green,"c",out=-110,in=-160] \ar[r,red,"b"] & 2 \ar[ur,blue,"a"] \ar[dr,green,"c"'] & {} & 5 \ar[r,red,"b"] & 6 \ar[loop,blue,"a",out=70,in=20] \ar[loop,green,out=-70,in=-20] \\
 & & 4 \ar[loop above,red,"b"] \ar[ur,blue,"a"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Problems:

1. What I want is to circle the two entries on the bottommost row; for the moment, I have a loop left, two no-head arrows pointing one cell too far (well, I would point them rr but I changed them to rrr to get them as they are), and a micro-parenthesis which is almost invisible; is there a way to get any kind of shape (possibly not a rectangle, I'd prefer something more curved, an oval, or a blob, but a rectangle will do if something curved is not feasible) to surround those entries?
2. "abel" (standing for "abelian", meaning the quotient of the two entries is abelian) is too close to the brace, and the brace has that extra little stroke; how do I remove the stroke and move "abel" further left?
3. Those loops are too squashed; I specified `in` and `out` angles correctly, but I want to take those arrows and "stretch" them in the direction orthogonal to them; more precisely, right now to obtain them one would have to take a `loop above` or `loop below` as the ones in the middle of the diagram, squash them vertically until they have almost zero height, then rotate them; how can I get those loops to look like what I described but without the squashing?

**Edit:**
Here is something close to what I want for 3, in particular the loops for V should be more slanted than this, like mirroring those for 6:

[image]

**Update:**

Problems 2 and 3 are fixed, as my answer states. Problem 1 has a touch of bizarre to it. I copy-pasted both answers' solutions into a file and compiled it, and they worked. Then I copy-pasted the solutions for diagram 1 into my old MWE. Here is what happened to LaRiFaRi's fix:

[image]

And here is Gonzalo's:

[image]

Gonzalo's actually has extra strangeness, in that on the first compilation it was identical to LaRiFaRi's, then I moved it vertically and the ellipse moved erratically, then I compiled it a few times and I saw it again like LaRiFaRi's, then I compiled it once more and the ellipse was gone, as you see above. So what is going on? And what are the `[alias…]` for?

**Update 2:**
I thought I had irremediably lost the possibility to retrieve those compilations' effects, but then I remembered I take a lot of screenshots when fiddling with LaTeX, so here are a few:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried a couple of fiddles, but to no avail:

[image]

[image]

Notice how Gonzalo's solution fixed the ellipse's placement as I fiddled with LaRiFaRi's.

**Update 3:**
More bizarreness. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,newtxmath,newtxtext,tikz-cd,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning,cd,fit,shapes.geometric}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\begin{document}

Gonzalo docet:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture,overlay]
  a 
  \ar[r,leftarrow] 
  \ar[d,rightarrow,red] 
& 
  id 
  \ar[r,rightarrow,red] 
& 
  b 
  \ar[d,rightarrow] 
\\
  ab 
  \ar[d,rightarrow] 
& 
& 
  ba 
  \ar[d,rightarrow,red] 
\\
  aba  
  & 
  & 
  bab
\end{tikzcd}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[ellipse,inner xsep=0pt,draw,blue,fit={(tikz@f@1-3-1) (tikz@f@1-3-3)}]   {};
}
\]

\vspace{2cm}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  G 
  \ar[d,thick, start anchor=center, end anchor=center,no head, xshift=-.5em,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror},"\text{\normalsize abel}" left=5pt] 
  \ar[d,no head] 
\\
  N 
\\
  G' 
  \ar[d,dashed,no head] 
\\
  \left\langle\mathcal{C}_1\right\rangle 
  \ar[d,no head] 
\\
  1
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& 
& 
  3 
  \ar[loop below,red,"b"] \ar[dr,green,"c"] 
\\
  V 
  \ar[loop above,blue,"a",out=155,in=105,looseness=7] 
  \ar[loop below,green,"c",out=-105,in=-155,looseness=7] 
  \ar[r,red,"b"] 
& 
  2 
  \ar[ur,blue,"a"] 
  \ar[dr,green,"c"'] 
& 
  {} 
& 
  5 
  \ar[r,red,"b"] 
& 
  6 
  \ar[loop,blue,"a",out=75,in=25,looseness=7] 
  \ar[loop,green,out=-25,in=-75,looseness=7] 
\\
& 
& 
  4 
  \ar[loop above,red,"b"] 
  \ar[ur,blue,"a"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

LaRiFaRi docet:
\[\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={\node[ellipse,draw,blue,fit={(tikz@f@1-3-1) (tikz@f@1-3-3)}]{};}]
a \arrow[red]{d} & \id \arrow{l}\arrow[red]{r} & b \arrow{d} \\
ab \arrow{d} & & ba \arrow[red]{d} \\
|[alias=X]|aba  & & |[alias=Y]|bab
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style=dash]
G \ar[thick, start anchor=center, end anchor=center, xshift=-.5em, decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror}]{d}[left= 4pt]{\text{abel}} \arrow{d} \\
N \\
G' \ar[d,dashed] \\
\left\langle\mathcal{C}_1\right\rangle \arrow{d} \\
1
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}
 & & 3 \ar[loop below,red,"b"] \ar[dr,green,"c"] \\
V \ar[loop,distance=20pt,blue,"a",out=160,in=110] \ar[loop,distance=20pt,green,"c",out=-110,in=-160] \ar[r,red,"b"] & 2 \ar[ur,blue,"a"] \ar[dr,green,"c"'] & {} & 5 \ar[r,red,"b"] & 6 \ar[loop,distance=20pt,blue,"a",out=70,in=20] \ar[loop,distance=20pt,green,out=-70,in=-20] \\
 & & 4 \ar[loop above,red,"b"] \ar[ur,blue,"a"]
\end{tikzcd}\]


\end{document}
```

First few runs it compiled identically to:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After fiddling with the screenshots from the other update (n. 2), I test it again and:

[image] [image]

[image]

And I'm like WTF??

Comment: Oh, and the loop for 4 should not be below but above, as in the code I gave.

Comment: `alias` gives an alias to the node. In this case it allows you to use `fit={(X)(Y)}` instead of `fit={(tikz@f@1-3-1) (tikz@f@1-3-3)}`.

Comment: I suspect the problem in your *Update 3* code is related to that Gonzalo's code has `remember picture, overlay`, which allows you to refer to node names outside the `tikzpicture` where they were defined. This is how Gonzalo drew the ellipse. If you for example remove Gonzalo's code from that example, LaRiFaRi's work fine. If you use `fit={(X)(Y)}` in LaRiFaRi's code, as I mentioned in my previous comment, both work fine.

Comment: Indeed. That fixes LaRiFaRi's solution. But Gonzalo's solution also shows erraticness in the ellipse, in Update 1-2. And if I try saying `|[alias=A]` in Gonzalo's solution, The result is `Use of \tikz@fig@scan@at doesn't match its definition`. How do I get aliases in Gonzalo's solution? In other words, why is that error coming up and how can I fix it? @TorbjørnT.

Comment: You need a closing `|` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gonzalo was quicker. Here a slightly different version which does not need to be compiled twice:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{newtxmath,tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,fit,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[execute at end picture={\node[ellipse,draw,blue,fit={(tikz@f@1-3-1) (tikz@f@1-3-3)}]{};}]
a \arrow[red]{d} & \id \arrow{l} \arrow[red]{r} & b \arrow{d} \\
ab \arrow{d}     &                              & ba \arrow[red]{d} \\
aba              &                              & bab
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style=dash]
G 
\arrow[%
    ,thick
    ,start anchor=center
    ,end anchor=center
    ,xshift=-.5em
    ,decorate
    ,decoration={%
        ,brace
        ,amplitude=4pt
        ,mirror
        }
    ]{d}[left=4pt]{\text{abel}} \arrow{d} \\
N \\[-3ex]
G' \arrow[d,dashed] \\
\langle\mathcal{C}_1\rangle \arrow{d} \\
1
\end{tikzcd}\]

\[\begin{tikzcd}
& & 3 \arrow[loop below,red,"b"] \arrow[dr,green,"c"] \\
V 
\arrow[loop,distance=16pt,blue,"a",out=150,in=120] \arrow[loop,distance=16pt,green,"c",out=-120,in=-150] \arrow[r,red,"b"] & 2 \arrow[ur,blue,"a"] \arrow[dr,green,"c"] & & 5 \arrow[r,red,"b"] & 6 \arrow[loop,distance=16pt,blue,"a",out=60,in=30] \arrow[loop,distance=16pt,green,out=-60,in=-30,swap,"c"] \\
& & 4 \arrow[loop above,red,"b"] \arrow[ur,blue,"a"]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The stroke in the second diagram was an arrow head. Just add the `dash` option to that arrow, as I did above.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: No matter, problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

1. You can use the `fit` library to fit an elliptical node around those elements; I used the remember picture, overlay options so the fitting node can be drawn outside the tikzcd environment. The code needs two or three runs for the ellipse to land in its final place.
2. You can use something like `left=<length>` to move the label. I also used `\text` from `amsmath` to write it in text mode.
3. You can use the `looseness` key.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,newtxmath,newtxtext,tikz-cd,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathreplacing,positioning,cd,fit,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[remember picture,overlay]
  a 
  \ar[r,leftarrow] 
  \ar[d,rightarrow,red] 
& 
  id 
  \ar[r,rightarrow,red] 
& 
  b 
  \ar[d,rightarrow] 
\\
  ab 
  \ar[d,rightarrow] 
& 
& 
  ba 
  \ar[d,rightarrow,red] 
\\
  aba  
  & 
  & 
  bab
\end{tikzcd}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
\node[ellipse,inner xsep=0pt,draw,blue,fit={(tikz@f@1-3-1) (tikz@f@1-3-3)}]   {};
}
\]

\vspace{2cm}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
  G 
  \ar[d,thick, start anchor=center, end anchor=center,no head, xshift=-.5em,decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=4pt,mirror},"\text{\normalsize abel}" left=5pt] 
  \ar[d,no head] 
\\
  N 
\\
  G' 
  \ar[d,dashed,no head] 
\\
  \left\langle\mathcal{C}_1\right\rangle 
  \ar[d,no head] 
\\
  1
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
& 
& 
  3 
  \ar[loop below,red,"b"] \ar[dr,green,"c"] 
\\
  V 
  \ar[loop above,blue,"a",out=155,in=105,looseness=7] 
  \ar[loop below,green,"c",out=-105,in=-155,looseness=7] 
  \ar[r,red,"b"] 
& 
  2 
  \ar[ur,blue,"a"] 
  \ar[dr,green,"c"'] 
& 
  {} 
& 
  5 
  \ar[r,red,"b"] 
& 
  6 
  \ar[loop,blue,"a",out=75,in=25,looseness=7] 
  \ar[loop,green,out=-25,in=-75,looseness=7] 
\\
& 
& 
  4 
  \ar[loop above,red,"b"] 
  \ar[ur,blue,"a"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem 3 is that the loops on `V` and `6` should not be up and down but slanted. I tried specifying `in` and `out` angles, and the result was terrible. How do I get them slanted without the losing their "height"?

Comment: @MickG Ah, I see. Give me some seconds.

Comment: @MickG Answer updated, Is it something like that what you need?

Comment: Absolutely. If you could make the distance between tip and tail of the loop arrows smaller it would be even better.

Comment: I guess that simply amounts to fiddling with the `in` and `out` angles, right?

Comment: @MickG Indeed, just use the `in` and `out` values that suit your needs.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: @MickG What exactly is the problem? Those screenshots tell me nothing.

Comment: Torbjørn solved it in his comments. If you look at the screenshots, you should see the ellipse moving freely around the page and/or losing its symmetry. Aliases fix that.

Comment: Well, of course using `alias` in my solution won't work, unless you change the internal names I used for those in `alias`. You're screenshots are useless. When you use `remember picture, overlay` you need to run the code twice for the elements to reach their final positions.

Comment: I changed the internal names indeed. I used names `XG` and `YG`, and now the `tikzcd_problems.tex` code gives the right output. It looks like LaRiFaRi's solution gave the aliases but didn't use them. Now it doesn't even give them. Anyway the problem is now solved. This need to compile twice might explain part of the erraticness, but the aliases surely need to fix the rest, because I'm sure that at least one of those screenshots came from a double compilation. Anyway the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a sum-up of the two answers to isolate the "tricks" that fixed the diagrams.

1. On hold as I encountered an additional problem, will update the question;
2. The extra bit of brace is actually the arrow head, which `no head` fixes; the positioning of the text is fixed by removing the comma before `left=`, which somehow caused that option to be ignored; I don't really see why I should say `\text{\normalsize abel}` instead of just `abel`; probably to avoid unneeded math mode; `\normalsize` seems to do pretty much nothing;
3. The trick with loops is the `looseness=`, or equivalently `distance=`, which if modified squashes or enlarges the loop.

**Edit:**
As LaRiFaRi points out in his answer, another fix to the extra stroke in 2 is `[every arrow/.append style=dash]` as optional argument to `\begin{tikzcd}`.

**Update:**
1 is solved. The additional problem is TikZ selecting the wrong tikz@f@1-3-1 or the likes. Using aliases to refer to those points fixes (or seems to fix) all the erratic behaviours of the ellipses, in both solutions. Accepting LaRiFaRi's version because it is `tikz-cd`-contained and doesn't require to do part of the diagram outside the diagram, but they are pretty much equivalent. Syntax for aliases: enclose the name of the alias between `|[alias=` (vertical bar, bracket, alias=) and `]|`, and don't forget the final closing vertical bar. Upvoting Gonzalo's work and accepting LaRiFaRi's.